# Does $\vec{a} \times \vec{b} = \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} \cdot \tan \varphi$ holds true?

Tags: vectors

Let $|\vec{v}| = v$.

We know that

$$ \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = a \cdot b \cdot \cos\varphi $$

and I have recently seen (on an old 'vocabulary' card) that (**Edit:** here is the mistake happening!)

$$ \vec{a} \times \vec{b} = a \cdot b \cdot \sin\varphi . $$

This would lead to

$$ \vec{a} \times \vec{b} = a \cdot b \cdot \sin\varphi \cdot \dfrac{\cos\varphi}{\cos\varphi} = \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} \cdot \dfrac{\sin\varphi}{\cos\varphi} = \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} \cdot \tan\varphi . $$

That 
$$ \vec{a} \times \vec{b} = \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} \cdot \tan\varphi $$
holds true seems very surprising to me.

**Edit:** *Where exactly is the mistake*, since the operations yield different types of outcomes?

Comment: lol dot product yields a scalar and cross product yields an orthogonal vector, so this is like asking whether an apple equals a banana

Comment: $$\vec a\times \vec b =\left(\frac{\vec a\times \vec b}{|\vec a\times \vec b|}\right)\,(\vec a\cdot \vec b)\,\tan(\theta)$$Note the unit vector in parentheses.  Take the magnitude of both sides and obtain  $$|\vec a\times \vec b |=|\vec a\cdot \vec b\,\tan(\theta)|$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the cross product of $\vec a $ and $\vec b$ is given by

$$\vec a\times \vec b=\left(\frac{\vec a\times \vec b}{|\vec a\times \vec b|}\right)\,|\vec a|\,|\vec b|\,\sin(\theta)$$

where $\frac{\vec a\times \vec b}{|\vec a\times \vec b|}$ is a unit vector that is normal to both $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ and has orientation that conforms to the right-hand rule.

---

The inner product is simply given by $\vec a\cdot \vec b=|\vec a|\,|\vec b|\,\cos(\theta)$.  Hence, we see that

$$\vec a\times \vec b =\left(\frac{\vec a\times \vec b}{|\vec a\times \vec b|}\right)\,(\vec a\cdot \vec b)\,\tan(\theta) \tag 1$$

---

Now, taking the magnitude of both sides of $(1)$ yields

$$|\vec a\times \vec b| =|\vec a\cdot \vec b|\,|\tan(\theta)| $$

Answer (score 0):

A vector can not be equal to a scalar. So the second equality is not true.

Answer (score 0):

The identity $\vec a \times \vec b = a*b*tan(\phi)$ is wrong. The LHS is a vector, the RHS is a scalar.